# Can an infinite sum depending on the logarithms of all positive integers be rational or algebraic?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

Consider
$$ C = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{f_1(n)} f_2(n) \log{n} + f_3(n)}{f_4(n)}$$

The sum converges. $f_1$ is either $0$ or $n-1$, $f_2,f_3,f_4$ are
polynomials with integer coefficients and $ f_2 \ne 0$.

> Q1. Can $C$ be non-zero rational or algebraic?

Comments suggest Q1 might be "hopeless".

> Q2. Can some similar variation of the sum depending on all $\log{n}$
>   and polynomials be rational or algebraic? There should be a single $\log{n}$ to avoid trivial telescoping.

**Added**

If one replaces $\log$ with $\sin$, things become easier.

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{(n-1)} \sin{n}}{n} = \frac{1}{2}$$

**Added**

Conjectured identity holding to at least 500 digits is:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{(n-1)}\log{n} = \frac{\log{2}-\log{\pi}}{2}$$

If it is true, it might "finish at least Q2 formally".

Comment: In other words, how much do we know about the arithmetic nature of the Euler‐Mascheroni constant, the Glaisher‐Kinkelin constant, the ... constant, etc. Alas, not much. Voting to close as hopeless.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is hopeless as of August 2013 AD.

Comment: @fedja if a certain choice of f_i make C rational this probably will have nothing to do with the constants you mention. As someone put it on meta "Voting on MO is close to voting in the real world".

Comment: You are right in the sense that if you allow "something like that" with sufficient leeway in the meaning of "like", it *might* be possible to design a clever cancellation and I'll even give it some thought. :) However, as written, you get all named constants of the type I mentioned (combined with $\pi^2$ and such) and a lot of nameless monsters in addition. Let's see. If the question is resolved in the current form, I'll certainly take my words back and apologize for being hasty to vote to close. However, as it is, I still "believe" that it is hopeless.

Comment: By the way, the words "non-zero" are completely redundant: we can always throw extra $\frac 1{n(n+1)}$ in, i.e. to add $1$ :).

Comment: @fedja Interpret "something like that" in a broad way, but I don't allow floor() and frac() :-)

Comment: I surmise $\sum_n \left[\frac{\log n}{n}-\frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1}\right]$ is also not what you are looking for. ;) So, could you formalize the restrictions in some reasonable way?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because as of now the question being asked is too vague. However, if it's edited to ask a precise question rather than "something like that" I will vote to reopen

Comment: @fedja telescoping logs are easy, the question is about a single log(), polynomials and (-1)^f(n). Btw, can you cancel to $\pi$ or $e$ ?

Comment: Single log may not be such a great formal requirement after all: take $\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1+2\cdot(-1)^{n-1})\frac{\log n}{n^2}$. It is a rational multiple of $\pi^2\log 2$ (couple each odd $v$ with all evens whose largest odd factor is $v$; the same telescoping but hidden a bit better). Whether $\pi^2\log 2$ can be written as a sum of a rational series or not, this is not what the spirit of the question is. We are still at the same fork between "possible but not exciting" and "exciting but impossible".

Comment: @fedja I will accept this as an answer. Do you have typo in your hidden telescoping? According to Wolfram Alpha your sum depends on log(pi), zeta'(2) and gamma: http://tinyurl.com/ocdc3qe

Comment: I think this is a real question, and don't see much concrete evidence either that it is trivial or hopeless.  So I would be in favour of reopening.

Comment: @Carl Is fedja's hidden telescoping really a rational multiple of $\pi^2\log 2$? Wolfram Alpha returns quite complicated answer given in my URL.

Comment: @joro I put it in mathematica, and get a relatively messy thing involving the Glaisher constant.  However dividing it by $\pi^2\log 2$ and evaluating numerically gives -1/6 to at least 100 digits.

Comment: @Carl Can you edit it so that the people who voted to close it would be satisfied with the new version? I believe I explained my point of view and what exactly I'm unhappy with rather clearly. :)

Comment: OK, the messy expression in the hidden telescoping indeed simplifies $-1/6\,{\pi }^{2}\ln  \left( 2 \right)$, so it is a solution.

Comment: @fedja you seem difficult to please - why is a solution involving $\pi^2\log 2$ not in the spirit of the question?  For more general series, what about polynomials or rational functions of $\log n$. These seem to violate the condition of "only one log," but is it obvious that these could be made to telescope?

Comment: Because the whole idea was to exclude "trivial telescoping". If I could somehow distinguish between odds, twice odds, and the rest, not just between odds and evens only, I would cancel $\log 2$ as well and finish it off formally without shedding any light on the real issue lurking behind. What's the point of such cunning trickery?

Comment: @Carl "what about polynomials or rational functions of $\log n$" Erm... What would be an example of a *convergent* series like that?

Comment: @fedja Your hidden telescoping appears quite sophisticated trick to dumb me. The partial sums depend on all logs unlike classical telescoping:  su1=sum( (-1+2*(-1)**(n-1))*log(n)/n^2,n,1,10);latex(su1) $$-\frac{3}{100} \, \log\left(10\right) + \frac{1}{81} \, \log\left(9\right) - \frac{3}{64} \, \log\left(8\right) + \frac{1}{49} \, \log\left(7\right) - \frac{1}{12} \, \log\left(6\right) + \frac{1}{25} \, \log\left(5\right) - \frac{3}{16} \, \log\left(4\right) + \frac{1}{9} \, \log\left(3\right) - \frac{3}{4} \, \log\left(2\right)  $$

Comment: @fedja $\sum (\log n)^2/n^2$.

Comment: @Carl Then you were just imprecise. You should say "polynomials and rational functions of $n$ and $\log n$. :) Normally I wouldn't attract attention to this but here the devil is in stating the problem in a good way to depart from the fork I mentioned, so every little detail matters :)

Comment: @fedja To be fair I said "more general;" presumably that would require some nontrivial $f$ polynomials.

Comment: OK, no real argument here: I do not deny interpretability and you don't deny ambiguity. Deal? :)

Comment: OK $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: @fedja edited the question with conjectured identity and relaxed the constraint on integer coefficients.

Comment: Have you ever seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product? I mean, we have reopened it, we made an effort to modify it, but are we really going anywhere here? (sigh)

Comment: The conjectured identity is for a series that doesn't converge!

Comment: @fedja Why don't you formulate your calculations as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, now you are arguing from my side, so I'll return the favor: use Chesaro or Abel-Poisson summation on it. :)

Comment: @Carl Let me just repeat what I said: "What's the point of cunning trickery?". We *do* have a real interesting problem here that I want to preserve. I just believe it is hopeless as of today.

Comment: The sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\log n$ is, formally, the value $-\eta'(0)$, where $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$ is the Dirichlet eta function. We indeed have $\eta'(0)=(\log\pi-\log 2)/2$. I don't see how this would "finish Q2 formally" though.